# How to download this video using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wget

I'm trying to make an python script to download videos from animefreak.tv so I can watch them offline while I'm on a roadtrip. Plus I thought it was a good opportunity to learn some webscraping.

I wrote this so far to download from this link http://animefreak.tv/watch/hacklegend-twilight-bracelet-episode-1-english-dubbed-online-free

```
URL = 'http://animefreak.tv/watch/one-piece-episode-1-english-dubbed-subbed'
IFRAME_POSITION = 2

# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(URL)
src = driver.page_source
parser = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')


driver.switch_to.frame(IFRAME_POSITION)
video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="player"]/div[2]/video')


touch = webdriver.TouchActions(driver)
touch.tap(video)
print('src: ', video.get_property('src'))

driver.close()
```

[image]

Whenever I run the script the src attribute doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

*interesting that you are using both beautifulsoup and selenium.  this task might be able to be accomplished using either one exclusively (with exceptions)*

You won't use Selenium to download the video, per se.  You'll use the language of choice. In your case, Python.

#### Python 2

```
import urllib
...
video_url = video.get_property('src')
urllib.urlretrieve(video_url, 'videoname.mp4')
```

#### Python 3

```
import urllib.request
...
video_url = video.get_property('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, 'videoname.mp4')
```

You'll probably have to calculate videoname.mp4 somehow so you don't get duplicates

Comment: I have a case where I need open the regular video page and the video_url in Selenium for the video_url to work, otherwise I'll get 403: Forbidden or even a "wrong cookie" message, would you have a suggestion for this case?

Comment: It's not work for me.
It's still runing for a long without any action ...